# NoRecaptcha 2 and Opera 12

Tags: javascript, opera, recaptcha

Obtain strange error in opera 12.16 under windows 7 (opera 12.16 under linux and other browsers work without any problems). When I click on "I'm not a robot" browser shows me an alert "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again." and in console:

```
    Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'a.window || oe(a.zg)' to object

Error thrown at line 5157, column 2 in <anonymous function: rj.prototype.send>(a, b, c) in https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20160307141848/recaptcha__en.js:
    (a.window || oe(a.zg)).postMessage(JSON.stringify({
called from line 10402, column 3 in <anonymous function: g.Di>(a, b, c) in https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20160307141848/recaptcha__en.js:
    vj(this.H, "anchor_" + a, ae().parent.frames[a], "*").send("anchor_" + a, "ready_challenge", new Mi(this.lf))
called from line 10259, column 2 in <anonymous function: g.Ya>(a) in https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20160307141848/recaptcha__en.js:
    this.l.wc.Di(u(this.Lk, this), u(this.Mk, this), u(this.Nk, this))
called from line 10439, column 2 in <anonymous function>(a) in https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20160307141848/recaptcha__en.js:
    (new dp(a)).Me().Ya(T(a, 1))
```

This error occurs in different places on different instances of site, but very stable. Cleaning of cache and debugging gave nothing.
There are some similar problem in google but nobody answers what to do.
Do you have any idea about this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few days ago google updated recaptcha code and the error message has disappeared... but instead of the message now we have infinite loop because recaptcha catches an error and tries to send data again. Such behavior is even worse than error message. The only way to "fix" it which I found - use fallback=true for script:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?fallback=true in opera instead of https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js
It's not an ideal solution but it works at least. I hope it will be useful for somebody who will face with similar problems.